# How to get string representation of common Qt5 types like QOpenGLContext?

Tags: c++, string, qt, qstring, qdebug

*NOTE: This is a rather naïve question on purpose.*

During debugging and logging in a **Qt5** **C++** application it is useful to print the value of internal variables, and in `Qt` the common way is to use `qDebug()` with friends like this:

```
qDebug()<<"The value was: "<< myVar;
// Usually works well even for built-in Qt types
```

This seems to work for many built-in Qt5 specific types, and even pointers as well, however in the cases where instead of outputting a log, we are in fact building a string this becomes much more cumbersome.

```
QString myString= "The value was: "+myVar;
// Usually doesn't work well for built-in Qt types
```

So the question is, what is a good general way to get the equivalent string representation of built-in Qt types as you would get from streaming them to qDebug()?

Or "what is the equivalent to Java toString() for `Qt` types"?

Comment: Whoever voted for closing this question, I really want to know your reason! How can it possibly be perceived as "opinion based"? What opinion is that exactly? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [QDebug class documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) I could find that it has constructor

```
QDebug::QDebug(QString *string)
```

> Constructs a debug stream that writes to the given string

So this should work:

```
QString myString;
QDebug stream(&myString);
stream <<"The value was: "<< myVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

The *format* and *contents* of Qt debug output are not a part of the API. They can change at any time. You will have to audit the output each and every time you update Qt, otherwise you must not depend on it other than for debugging. That's why the APIs make it purposefully cumbersome to convert between debug output and strings.

Instead, implement your own `QTextStream` operators for types that you need, and use the stream to build the strings.

Comment: Would not the usefulness and convenience of such conversions arguably outweigh these concerns? In worst case it could be explicitly mentioned in the documentation that under no circumstances should the output be depended uppon for other purposes than debugging.

Comment: If you're debugging, use `qDebug` already. You're free to reimplement the message handlers to capture the output and e.g. log it, etc. But you don't need to deal with manual conversions to strings at all.